# I need to find out what patches have been installed on my Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, patch

Does anybody know the command line to find out what patches were installed on Ubuntu? I did not install any additional package, only the main software.
I looked up the Ubuntu documentation and only found the command line that lists the applications installed.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not really about programming, maybe should be better moved to askubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Check apt history:

```
 less /var/log/apt/history.log
```

This will tell you about installation activity.

Answer (score 1):

in a wide sense, a patch is a diff file that you can apply to source code. if and how you deal with the patched source code is not documented centrally in ubuntu, since you're free to compile it and do whatever you like with it. also, there's no registry or so that stores the list of every installed tool. some things are just copied via `make install` to `/opt` or `/usr/local` so that it's hard to track updates to software like this.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to linux and am still trying to figure things out.

Comment: Pretty sure the question is about Ubuntu package updates, not source code diffs.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking there are no patches installed on Ubuntu, but new packages that replace (upgrade) older ones, preserving configuration files. The logfile `/var/log/dpkg.log` contains information on new and upgraded packages.

The debian packages ask for inclusion of a Changelog. They can be found at `/usr/share/doc/<packagename>`. There is a also a nice tool named `apticron` that sends you by email a summary of pending package upgrades on your system on a daily basis.